# decryption for password reverse to ASCII code multiple location

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to create procedure a to decrypt a password reverse ASCII code multiple location char and concatenation with ASCII

example password: 123 
encrypted to: 49491005015351

It's encrypted like this:

```
v := v || ASCII(substr(u_pass,i,1)) * instr(u_pass,substr(u_pass,i,1))
```

Comment: This is not a very good algorithm to encrypt something. DO NOT write your own encryption algorithm. Use the inbuilt ones in [dbms_crypto](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm) (this is not a recommendation. You need to decide what is best for you.)

Comment: Furthermore, your "encryption" seems to be done in a loop. It's impossible for someone to reverse engineer without all the details.

Comment: Also password algorithms are generally not designed for decryption -- you encrypt the submitted password and see if the result matches the stored password encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the reverse is that the length of each encrypted character can vary.
Note that the algorithm below looks for the shortest sequence that gives a character. There may be instances when this is incorrect. In those instances this code will fail to decrypt the remainder of the string.

```
v := <encrypted password>;

i := 1;    -- Character
pos := 1;  -- Position in v
while (pos < length(v)) loop
  j=1;
  found = false;
  while not found  and j + pos <= length(v) loop
    if mod(to_number(substr(v, pos, j), i) = 0 then  
      -- Possible match
      anum := to_number(substr(v, pos, j)/ j;  -- ascii value of the next character
      alen := length(trim(to_char(anum)));
      if substr(v, pos + j, alen) = anum then
        -- Match found!
        u_pass := u_pass || chr(anum);
        found := true;
        pos := pos + j + alen;
        i := i + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
end loop;
```